# Troubles with implementing a Fourier-transform formula

Tags: equations

I am trying to write a formula, which includes operators Re{}, F(\omega) and e(). Anyways, it doesn't work, I know I must be missing some parantheses, but I can't figure out where or what else might be wrong:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, oneside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[free-standing-units]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{Re}\left{\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}{\inf} 2F(\omega) \operatorname{e}^{i\omega t} d\omega \right}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\left{` should be `\left\{` (similarly for `\right`). If you want an upright font for the Euler number, use `\mathrm{e}`, not `\operatorname{e}`, which is wrong. By the way, `\mathcal{Re}` prints a funny symbol instead of an “e”; probably you meant `\mathrm`, but *this* should be `\operatorname{Re}`. Also infinity is `\infty`, not `\inf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- You meant to write `\infty` rather than `\inf`, right? Don't forget typing `^` to place `\infty` in the upper limit of integration.
- Write `\mathrm{e}` for Euler's number.
- To generate curly braces, you need to write `\{` and `\}`, respectively.
- `\mathcal` is only implemented, at least in the `amssymb` package, for uppercase letters.
- It's somewhat customary, though by no means required, to insert a thinspace between the integrand and the variable of integration.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\mathcal{R}\left\{\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \! 2F(\omega) \mathrm{e}^{i\omega t}\, d\omega \right\}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```